# How do I register a .NET assembly to the GAC and register it for COM in WIX? (Regasm)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wix, registry

I am making a custom tool (code generator) for VS2008.  I have the wix installer putting in all the registry entries for the visual studio, but what it is not doing is the equivalent of `regasm mytool.dll`

It is getting into the GAC by virtue of the  Assembly=".net" attribute of the File element. But I am not even entirely sure that getting into the GAC matters.  I think it would work with a `regasm /codebase mytool.dll`

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? <a href="http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson5.php">http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson5.php</a> Also, look at this post: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543995/replicating-visual-studio-com-registration-with-a-wix-installer">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543995/replicating-visual-studio-com-registration-with-a-wix-installer</a>

Comment: It helps a bit.  It looks like the current answer is to use the Heat tool on the dll.  I'd like something a bit more simple however.

Comment: Here's the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205188/whats-the-correct-way-of-registering-installing-an-assembly-to-the-gac/205243#205243) to my answer to that ...