# Extract registry information from ActiveX exe

Tags: registry, activex, dcom

I have a DCOM client/server application (VB6) and using Installshield 2011 to extract the registry entries of the server and add them to the client project. However, the extraction doesn't extract all entries.

One important key is the 'LocalServer32' key. Thus, on installation, the server is not set up as a DCOM application due to these missing keys.

Is there any other tool that can successfully extract all registry entries of an ActiveX exe?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/546363/1768303